# Iterate a function R code

Tags: r, loops

I have a function `myF(g,m,alpha,gam,theta,beta)`. Which returns three estimates of parameters. I want to iterate this function for `(i in 1:10)`. How can i do this it in R?

```
   myF <- function(g,m,alpha,gam,theta,beta){

    dat <- sim.data(g,m,alpha,gam,theta,beta)
    time <- dat$times
    delta <- dat$cens
    i <- dat$group
    X1<-dat$cov #cov~rbinom
    n <- length(levels(as.factor(i))) 
    di <- aggregate(delta,by=list(i),FUN=sum)[,2]
    D <- sum(di)
     loglik <- function(par){
     .........................................
           return(-lik)
     }

    initial=c(0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5)
    maxF <- nlm(loglik, initial)
    return(c(theta=exp(maxF$estimate[2]),beta1=maxF$estimate[3],alpha=exp(maxF$estimate[2])))
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `iterate`? Do you mean call the function ten times (the same way each time)? Do you want to provide different parameters, or use the parameters it returns somehow?

Comment: Yes I want to run for loop upto 10 times. From this I will get total 3*10=30 estimate of parameters.

Comment: And you want to give the function the exact same inputs each time?

Comment: In that case `replicate` is what you want. See my answer below.

Comment: How is `sim.data` defined?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using `replicate`:

```
replicate(10, myF(g,m,alpha,gam,theta,beta))
```

This will create a 3*10 matrix of the parameter estimates, where each column is the result of a separate iteration.

Comment: This does not work as my desired one. This gives same value for all iteration. But it have to generate some little different value all time due to data set which comes from binomial distribution randomly.

Comment: @Rudro88: You said you wanted to give it the same `g`, `m`, `alpha` parameters: if `myF` is deterministic this will mean it always gives the same output. Are you saying that the `myF` function uses the binomial distribution inside it (and is therefore not deterministic)? Could you post the code of `myF`?